# get only row that meet condition if such row exist and if not get the row that meet another condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

this sounds like a simple question but I just cant find the right way.
given the simplified  table

```
with t as  (
select   ordernumber, orderdate,  case when ordertype in (5,21) then 1 else 0 end is_restore , ordertype, row_number() over(order by orderdate) rn from
( 
select to_date('29.08.08','DD.MM.YY') orderdate,'313' ordernumber, 1  as ordertype  from dual union all
select to_date('13.03.15','DD.MM.YY') orderdate, '90/4/2' ordernumber, 5  as ordertype from dual
)
)
select * from t -- where clause  should be here
```

[image: Input data]

for every row  is_restore guaranteed to be 1 or 0.
if table has a row where is_restore=1  then select ordernumber,orderdate of that row and nothing else.
If a table does not  have a row where is_restore=1  then select ordernumber,orderdate  of the row where rn=1(row where rn=1 is guaranteed to exist in a table) 
 Given the requirements above   what do I need   to put in where clause  to get  the following?

[image: desirable output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
CREATE TABLE t
AS
select ordernumber, orderdate,
    case when ordertype in (5,21) then 1 else 0 end is_restore, ordertype,
    row_number() over(order by orderdate) rn
  from ( 
     select to_date('29.08.08','DD.MM.YY') orderdate,'313' ordernumber,
           1  as ordertype 
     from dual union all
     select to_date('13.03.15','DD.MM.YY') orderdate, '90/4/2' ordernumber,
            5  as ordertype
     from dual);

-------------------

with cte as (
  select t.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(/*PARTITION BY ...*/ ORDER BY is_restore DESC, rn) AS rnk
  from t
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a9aec059fdac6d5d6107bfe563813a04)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is sql, that doesn't use window functions, maybe it will be useful for those, whose databases don't support OVER ( ... ) or when there are indexed fields, on which query is based.

```
SELECT
* 
FROM t
WHERE t.is_restore = 1 
OR (
 NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE t.is_restore = 1)
 AND t.rn = 1
)
```

Comment: An explanation, what the posted code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.

Comment: Ask a question if you don't understand the answer, please. 
What should I explain here?

Comment: This is a general advise as your answer ended up in the "low quality review queue" because it *just* contains code. And it normally is no effort to add a few words explaining *what the posted code does and how this addresses the problem in the question*. Here there was already an answer when you posted yours. So why not telling why you think your approach is better? Or you could tell what your answer adds to the already existing answer. These just as a few thoughts.